# Dynamic news required from different hosting server

Tags: php, feed

I have a simple php website and I want to display my company news on homepage. I don't want to write html and upload on the server to display news. Is there any website that provides us basic CMS to create news and give us a short code that I can integrate on my website? And whenever I need to add news I will add on their website and it reflects on my website homepage.

Comment: Add a RSS reader to your website and create RSS online using various sites such as http://www.rapidfeeds.com/

Answer (score 0):

The best route to go is to probably build either the entire site in Wordpress or build the news section within a subfolder like sitename.com/news. It's probably the most complete news/blogging engine out there, and it's easy to pick up.

If you host it in a subfolder, and still want to reference the articles outside of Wordpress, just be sure to include this in top of your home page:

```
<?php
   // Include Wordpress 
   define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
   require('news/wp-blog-header.php');
   query_posts('showposts=2');
?>
```

Just be sure to change the require() to point to your directory, and change the showposts count to the number of articles you want to show.

Wordpress has lots of other great resources on learning how to use it if you're not familiar.
http://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: Hi Chris, I have installed the wordpress and created some posts on my local machine. Everything in the WordPress is working fine but I am not able to fetch the posts in simple php page. I have used the code that you suggested but nothing is coming. Please guide...